# What's the "u'" at the beginning of every field in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

There's nothing here because the question fit into the title field.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+string+u are related questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably, you're using the Python client, and seeing [Unicode strings](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type).